# Objective C - Read plaintext multicolumn file into several column arrays

Tags: objective-c, io, textinput

I have seen several threads about file handling in Objective C but can't find a simple systematic way to do this: let's say you have a multicolumn data files where each x y z ... columns are separated by tabs. What I want to do is just converting each column to a specific array. I have almost no experience with Objective C but I do know C++.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use a NSString method to do this after reading it with `stringWithContentsOfFile:...`:

- split it into a line-array with `componentsSeperatedByString:@"\n"`
- split each line-array line with `componentsSeperatedByString:@"\t"`

Comment: Can't get it to work : NSString * zStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:zUrl                                           encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];
NSArray *table=[zStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; thanks for the help anyways
    
    NSArray *x =[table componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"];